# How to get the method name that thrown the exception in Java

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I have an aspect that runs after an exception is thrown from my TestNG test method. I would like to get the Test method name into my aspectj method.

Any thoughts on this? Please find my code sample below:

Aspect:

```
pointcut publicCall(): call(public * *(..));

after() throwing (AssertionError e): publicCall() {
    logger.debug("Assertion Error thrown");
    System.out.println("Threw an exception: " + e);
}
```

Test:

```
@Test

public void testScenarioOne(){
    logger.debug("From Scenario One Test");
    Assert.assertEquals(true, false);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your pointcut type from `call` to `execution`:

```java
pointcut publicMethod(): execution(public * *(..));

after() throwing (AssertionError e): publicMethod() {
    System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature());
}
```

**Edit:** Maybe it would be even cleaner to specifically intercept `@Test` annotated methods:

```java
import org.testng.annotations;

public aspect TestExceptionInterceptor {
    pointcut testMethod(): execution(@Test * *(..));

    after() throwing (AssertionError e): testMethod() {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Changing the pointcut type from call to execution did the trick. (the second snippet didn't get compiled).

Comment: As far as I remember, I just copied & pasted the second snippet from my editor where it compiled just fine. Can you be more specific? Which error message do you get?

Comment: The error you got was likely because you need to specify the fully qualified package such as pointcut testMethod(): execution(@org.testng.annotations.Test * *(..));

Comment: Why do you comment on a question which was accepted more than two years ago? BTW, the comment is false. In native AspectJ syntax fully qualified names are unnecessary because you can refer to imported classes with simple names. Only in annotation-based @AspectJ syntax this is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName()
```

although you will have to throw the exception directly from your test method. `Assert.equals()` is throwing the exception not your test method.

Comment: Well... Thankyou! but that's giving me "assertEquels" method. I need the Test method (ie. testScenarioOne).